# Why is $\phi$ onto if $X$ is path connected in Hatcher's exercise 1.1.6?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**1.1.6**: We can regard $π_1(X,x_0)$ as the set of basepoint-preserving homotopy classes of
maps $(S_1, s_0)→(X,x_0)$. Let $[S_1,X]$ be the set of homotopy classes of maps $S_1→X$,
with no conditions on basepoints. Thus there is a natural map $\phi :π_1(X,x_0)→[S_1,X]$
obtained by ignoring basepoints. Show that $\phi$ is onto if $X$ is path-connected, and that
$\phi([f ]) = \phi([g])$ iff $[f ]$ and $[g]$ are conjugate in $\phi_1(X,x_0)$. Hence $\phi$ induces a one to-one correspondence between $[S1,X]$ and the set of conjugacy classes in $π_1(X)$, when X is path-connected.

Suppose that $X$ is path connected, I want to show that $\phi$ is onto.

I don't understand why path connectedness is needed here. Take any $[f]\in \pi_1(X,x_0)$. $f:I\to X$ is a loop based at $x_0$.  By universal property of quotient maps, there exists a unique $\tilde f: S^1\to X, \tilde f\circ q=f,$ where $q:I\to S^1$ is the quotient map.

So I define $\phi([f])= [\tilde f]$.

To show that $\phi$ is onto, let $[g] \in [S^1, X]$ be chosen arbitrarily. Then, we have as per the definition above $\phi([g\circ q])=[g]$ so $g$ is onto.

What is wrong with the above and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: $[g \circ q]$ need not be in the domain of $\phi$.

Comment: If you consider X to be a discrete set with two points you can probably intuitively feel what goes wrong.

Comment: Take $X = (\mathbb R - \{0\}) \times \mathbb R$, a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Take $x_0 = (1,0) \in X$. Take any continuous $g : S^1 \to (-\infty,0) \times \mathbb R \subset X$; for example, choose $g$ to parameterize the circle of radius $1$ centered at $(-2,0)$.  What loop in $X$ based at $x_0$ can you choose to represent the homotopy class of $g$ in $[S_1,X]$?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: I understood that. Thanks a lot :-).

Answer (score 2):

Consider a space $X$ having more than one path-component. Let $P_0$ be the path-component of $x_0$. Then each map $f : (S^1,s_0) \to (X,x_0)$ has image in $P_0$. Given a map $F : S^1  \to X$ with image in a path-component $P \ne P_0$, it cannnot be homotopic to map with image in $P_0$. Thus $[F] \notin \phi(\pi_1(X,x_0))$.

If $X$ is path-connected, then $\phi$ is indeed onto. Given any map $F : S^1 \to X$, we have to find $f : (S^1,s_0) \to (X,x_0)$ such that $f \simeq F$. Le $x_1 = F(s_0)$ and  $F' = F \circ q : I \to X$. Choose a path $u : I \to X$ such that $u(0) = x_0$ and $u(1) = x_1$. The loop
$$F'' : I \to X, F''(s) = \begin{cases} x_1 & s \le 1/3 \\ F'(3s-1) & 1/3 \le s \le 2/3 \\ x_1 & 2/3 \le s \end{cases}$$
is homotopic rel. $\{0,1\}$ to the loop $F'$.

Define a homotopy
$$H : I \times I \to X, H(s,t) = \begin{cases} u(t + 3s(1-t)) & s \le 1/3 \\ F'(3s-1) & 1/3 \le s \le 2/3 \\ u(t + 3(1-s)(1-t)) & 2/3 \le s \end{cases}$$
Then $H(0,t) = H(1,t) = u(t)$ for all $t \in I$ which means that $H_t = H(-,t) : I \to X$ is a loop based at $u(t)$. Moreover $H_1 = F''$.

The map $Q = q \times id_I : I \times I \to S^1  \times I$ is a quotient map and by construction $H$ is constant on all fibers $Q^{-1}(z,t)$ of $Q$ (which are singletons if $z \ne s_0$ or hav ethe form $\{0,1\} \times \{t\}$ for $z = s_0$). Thus $H$ induces a homotopy $h : S^1 \times I \to X$. Leeting $f = h_0$, we see that $f(s_0) = x_0$ and $f \simeq F$.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you. Another problem in my post is: goq need not be based at $x_0$.