# What exactly is the proof of onto here?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, path-connected

I have been reading the solution of the following question:

We can regard $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ as the set of basepoint-preserving homotopy classes of maps $(S^1,s_0) \to (X, x_0).$ Let $[S^1, X]$ be the set of homotopy classes of maps $S^1\to X,$ with no conditions on basepoints. Thus there is a natural map $\Phi: \pi_1(X, x_0) \to [S^1, X]$ obtained by ignoring basepoints. Show that
$(a)$ $\Phi$ is onto if $X$ is path-connected,\
$(b)$ Show that $\Phi([f]) = \Phi([g])$ iff $[f]$ and $[g]$ are conjugate in $\pi_1(X, x_0).$

Here: [Why is $\phi$ onto if $X$ is path connected in Hatcher's exercise 1.1.6?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672828/why-is-phi-onto-if-x-is-path-connected-in-hatchers-exercise-1-1-6?rq=1)

I am not quite sure where exactly is the proof of onto in this solution, could someone clarify this to me please?(I want a proof without using Homotopy extension property please if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\Phi$ is onto is quite simple. All it means is that every loop $f:[0,1]\to X$ is (freely) homotopic to a loop based at $x_0$. If $X$ is path connected, then there is a path $\lambda:[0,1]\to X$ from $x_0$ to $f(0)=f(1)$. Then $f$ is freely homotopic to the [path composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Path_composition) $\lambda * f*\lambda^{-1}$, which is a loop based at $x_0$. And this follows from general homotopic properties of path composition.

Comment: does freely homotopic means independent of the basepoint?

Comment: @Brain "independent" maybe not correct word. It means that it doesn't fix/preserve basepoint, yes.

Comment: is this a proof of the onto part only or the injective also?

Comment: why you choose specifically this path composition in line 3?

Comment: @Brain only onto. This map does not have to injective, see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458349/base-point-homotopy-vs-free-homotopy-example

Comment: @Brain this path composition just works. A path that goes forwards and then backwards is nullhomotopic. That's what makes the construction work.

Comment: but where is the arbitrary path in the codomain that you found for it an element in the domain of $\Phi$ that $\Phi$ maps to this element of the codomain .... The usual definition of an onto map.

Comment: @Brain the answer should be understood as: $\Phi([\lambda *f*\lambda^{-1}])=[f]$.

Comment: but you did not name the loop based at $x_0$ right? Which is the element in the codomain

Comment: @Brain I don't understand your question. $\lambda*f*\lambda^{-1}$ is a loop based at $x_0$ by construction.